# php4 escape input with postgres options

Tags: php, php4, psql

I have a server that only has php4 and postgresql. As far as I can tell PDO and pg_query_params don't exist in php4. What alternatives are there? Or is raw escaping the only option?

Comment: One alternative is updating your version of PHP

Comment: PHP4 has reached EOL and is not supported anymore. It is not only irresponsible but a huge risk to have that piece of software installed on your server. Upgrade now, or if you're on shared hosting, run far away from the host.

Comment: Agreed.  PHP 4 has been deprecated for years.  The first priority should be not running your site on ancient, bug-ridden software.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR DB started out in PHP 4; you can probably still find a version somewhere that supports it.  I used to use it before switching to PHP 5 and PDO; it's pretty decent if you're stuck with PHP 4.

Really, though, your priority should be to get as far away from PHP 4 as possible.  It hasn't been supported for years, sucks at handling objects, and is wretchedly slow compared to PHP 5.  Plus, PHP 5 has PDO.